# QGIS auxiliary rotation of the label not working properly

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am using the rotation feature from the main panel at the top.
Unfortunately it doesn't work properly for all the labels. I've categorized my labels, so now I have the "Black" category and the "Red" category.
All of them have auxiliary fields stored in the data attribute table.
The problem is, that one of them can be editable straight from the panel - this is the black one, whereas the red one cannot be rotated at all (unless you click the "move label" from the panel).
You can see all the details below:

[image]

I would like to be able to rotate also the red labels.
The image above shows the problem and all the settings. Both X,Y, and rotation are enabled in all cases as well as the expression referred to the auxiliary storage are the same in both cases. Where the problem might be then?

Comment: Have you moved one of the red labels before? I couldn't rotate it before moving it.

Comment: No, I haven't. Shall I do it?

Comment: I suggest you try and report, what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this problem seems to be quite simple.

[image]

In the "Placement" section we should switch off (Deactivate) X and Y coordinates including the auxiliary geometry.
If we leave just rotation active with marked "Preserve data rotation values", then I am able to rotate the feature keeping its placement based on the expression instead of auxiliary conditions.